# Why is the function $f(x)=\tan(1/x)$ undefined at $x=0$?

Tags: limits

Why is the function $f(x)=\tan(1/x)$ undefined at $x=0$? And why can't I take its limit at $x=0$?

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}1/x$ supposed to be, exactly? Do you see the issue here?

Comment: Since the division by zero is not defined it can be defined $\tan(1/x)$ at $x=0$.

Comment: sorry for the image:) but could you plz explain a lil bit about tan 1/x only becoz ts graph is lil bit confusing near zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\tan(1/x)$ is not defined at $0$ because $1/x$ itself isn't defined at $0$ (you can't divide by zero).

One way to see that the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \tan(1/x)$ does not exist is to note that $\tan(1/x)$ takes any value arbitrarily close to $0$ (for any $\delta > 0$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$, you can find $0 < x < \delta$ such that $\tan(1/x) = y$). This is because $\tan$ is surjective on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and $\pi$-periodic, and so it is surjective on arbitrarily "far away" intervals of the form $(-\pi/2 + k\pi, \pi/2 + k\pi)$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: now i completely got it that tan x can take any arbitrarily value at close to 0 but the function like log x remains negative infinity at zero... thats why they are defined but tan x is undefined

Comment: @ShubhankarMondal One example that may interest you is $\sin(x)/x$. It is undefined at $0$ but its limit there exists and is equal to $1$. This is essentially because $\sin x$ behaves very much like $x$ when $x$ is very small ("small-angle approximation").

Comment: Note, however, that it is entirely possible for a function $f(1/x)$ to have a removable singularity at $x=0$. All that is required is that $f$ have the same finite limits at $\pm\infty$.

Comment: why cant i use squeeze theorem similar to xsinx here.. ie why cant i use this inequality (-1<=sinx<=1) in both xsin x and sin(x)/x...